# Does Windows recognize Linux's symbolic links?

Tags: windows, symlink, macos

I was just wondering how a Windows system handles symbolic links (when created via Linux's `ln -s` on a filesystem that Windows natively supports *and* that supports symbolic links, such as NTFS). My best guess is that it will not recognize them, but I'm not entirely sure.

Also, what do Macs do when confronted by one?

Comment: How do you plan to expose Windows to a symbolic link? It doesn't understand filesystems that support them (except NTFS, which has something not entirely unlike symbolic links that is mostly hidden from the UI).

Comment: Oh.. so what happens if you've mounted your Windows partition, and you try to put a symbolic link in it? Does it just work as if it were a folder? (If so, I wonder what happens with RECURSION...)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Depends on the Windows version and the configuration of the server-side when we talk about non-local disks.

Since Windows Vista, Windows does have an idea of symbolic links, but the semantics differ. But the more important problem here should be the path names, which follow a different syntax. For starters: single-rooted directory tree on the unixoid side and several drive letters as roots on the Windows side.

On the unixoid side symlinks are merely text files with a special flag. On the Windows side the underlying mechanism is called a reparse point. This tells the object manager to to pass it to particular registered filters (the meta-date for this is stored *in* the reparse points). Windows 2000 already introduced one type of reparse points known as junction points (roughly, but not quite, directory symlinks). With Vista they introduced symlinks to both files and directories, also on remote drives. And symlinks *on* remote drives are also supported to some extent.

The main point is whether the file system driver - when run locally - would do any adjustments to the paths Windows gets to see. In such a case it would work for certain local/relative symlinks. For absolute paths as targets things will get difficult and impossible to deduce what's meant. Same for remote symlinks links (to "network shares").

As for the Mac side I have no idea and it might make sense as a separate question. But as long as the server side conveys the information that this is a symlink, I see no problems, since they both follow the SUS semantics (unlike Windows).

---

Consider the Linux side mount points:

```
/dev/sda1 /
/dev/sda2 /home
/dev/sda3 /var
```

And now consider a symlink `/home/paul/fstab` pointing to `/etc/fstab`. They are located on two different volumes which Windows - if able to see them through a file system driver (which does work!) - can't tell belong together the way `/etc/fstab` describes it. So the link, which Windows would see under a folder `\paul\fstab`, even if translated, would point to `\etc\fstab`, which doesn't exist on `/dev/sda2`. And if that symlink would point to the relative path `../../etc/fstab` things wouldn't change at all.

---

**The gist:** So while this is conceivable that you can get this to work for some corner cases, the fact that semantics and syntax differ on both sides of the fence makes it unlikely that you will find a practical and generic method that works.

Comment: Wow, this was a very detailed, thorough answer! Thank you for providing all this information! I actually had no idea that Linux's symlinks were text-based. Thank you again for all the useful information here.

Comment: can you please help me on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403772/how-to-use-reuse-softlinks-created-on-mac-in-windows-8

Comment: I think I have done a sym-link on XP, are you sure that vista was the first?

Comment: `ntfs` supports mount points (for if you don't like all those letters).

Comment: @richard: in fact volume mount points *are* the technical term for what you see as drive letters in the Win32 subsystem. However, you are right in the sense that a volume mount point can also be set on an existing folder (which is very similar to junction points). The technical feature used to implement volume mount points, junction points and symbolic links is called **reparse points**. And yes, Vista was the first to have symbolic link support. On XP you could have done it only in another subsystem (e.g. POSIX) which, however, has different semantics, like the above.

Comment: I for sure did symlinks in XP, using the `cmd`. I think I had to enable them somewhere first though, a registry setting I think.

Comment: @richard: please enlighten me then, because that would signify a huge gap of knowledge for me. Or do you perhaps mean junction points, which existed since Windows 2000 and are also a type of reparse points. So these are similar, but by no means the same as symlinks. The main differences: symlinks can point to to files, to non-existent locations at the time of creation, to network paths (`\\server\share\directory`)

Comment: @richard: do you perhaps mean the *driver* and the [shell extension mentioned here](http://superuser.com/a/117177)? Because if yes, that's true, a third-party file system filter driver *is* indeed capable to handle reparse points, even those created on Windows Vista and newer, in a fashion that mimics the handling on on Vista and newer. But that's not on-board-functionality. And since you seem to claim a mere setting was necessary to enable it, I'm still interested in what that alleged setting was etc. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude Pretty much everything in Linux is text-based. (:

Answer (score 1):

0xC0000022L's answer is thorough for the Windows side of things. The Mac can recognize Linux's symlinks; however Linux cannot recognize *aliases* made in the Mac's Finder (symlinks created using ln -s work fine).

Comment: sounds like *aliases* are the OSX counterpart to shortcuts on Windows (`.lnk` files).